# Доступ к объекту формы из другой программы

Tags: c#, messagebox, форма

Предположим, стоит следующая простая задача: есть форма с одной кнопкой, по нажатию на которую, к примеру, вылетает `messageBox`. И эта программа уже запущена. Нужно получить доступ уже из другой программы к объекту этой запущенной формы и просто вызвать нажатие на эту кнопку (чтобы вылетел `messageBox`).

Я попробовал написать крохотную отдельную библиотеку с одним методом, где у меня есть доступ ко всем классам этой запускаемой программы (в том числе к классу запускаемой формы). Но я что-то никак не могу получить именно доступ к объекту той, уже запущенной формы. Максимум, что могу, - это только создать еще один экземпляр той же формы, открыв программу 2-ой раз, и вызвать метод события клика из неё, а это не совсем то. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добрый день!

Ну, во-первых, к какой программе обращаетесь (Net'вской или win32)? Если к win32, тогда надо использовать WinAPI (используйте GetWindow чтобы получить хендл окна, а затем и контролов). Ну а если это Net программа, можно попробовать получить список контролов окна: (добавьте `using System.Diagnostics`).

```
 Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses("Name process");
 foreach(Process p in processes)
 {
    if(p.StartInfo.FileName=="Name EXE")
 {
    IntPtr hWindow = p.MainWindowHandle; 
    Control mainForm = Form.FromHandle(hWindow); 
    ControlCollection childControls = mainForm.Controls;
 }
 }
```

Comment: @ghost rider, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.